# Scrolling in "RepeatBox" control is not smooth

Tags: smartface.io

I have two pages, first page I have a `ScrollView` control and the other page I used `RepeatBox` control.

My problem is the `ScrollView` page scroll is smooth, But the `RepeatBox` page scrolling is not smooth (i.e. flickering while scrolling).

Could any one help on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of repeatbox can change according to the objects you used in it. Because it is drawn with rowRender event, it can take more time with different objects. Also, in some old devices, especially for Android, you can see these kind of performance differences in applications.

Maybe you can test with other devices, or you can test with more simple project in order to see if it is always flickering or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes with all images on the visible screen are opening again from the local storage by rowRender method. In the native RepeatBox after image comes on visible area are stored and not again opening from local storage and creates performance problem.